# Renaming multiple files with multiple "." within them

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I am fairly new to programming or scripting so I hope the terms I am using would be the right ones.

1.I am trying to rename multiple files withing multiple folders.

2.I do not know the names of the folders, I can only know the folders hosting those sub-folder, each folder is assigned with a  different Time&Date stamp

3.I do not know the name of the files each folder contain

4.In each one of those folders, the name of the files are exactly the same as in the other folders

5.**I do know** the files extension within all the folders -"**.t**"

So what i am trying to do is the following:

Original files:

Folder Name: ***FolderA***

"Log1000_1.1.1.1_Base.1.textlog.t"

"Log1000_1.1.1.1_Base.2.textlog.t"

Folder Name: ***FolderB***

"Log1000_1.1.1.1_Base.1.textlog.t"

"Log1000_1.1.1.1_Base.2.textlog.t"

**Wanted result:**

Folder Name: ***2015-02-19%3A224044***

"Log1000_1.1.1.1_Base.***1.2015-02-19%3A224044.textlog***"

"Log1000_1.1.1.1_Base.***2.2015-02-19%3A224044.textlog***"

Folder Name: ***1.2015-02-19%3A224060***

"Log1000_1.1.1.1_Base.***1.2015-02-19%3A224060.textlog***"

"Log1000_1.1.1.1_Base.***2.1.2015-02-19%3A224060.textlog***"

And so on...

I have tried the following code:

```
cd C:\DataCollection\ClassOne

REM Creating a list of all folders

dir /b /a:d >>C:\DataCollection\ClassOne\tempfolderlist.txt

for /R /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\DataCollection\ClassOne\tempfolderlist.txt) do (
        cd C:\C:\DataCollection\ClassOne\%%A
        ren *.t *%%A.textlog
)
```

I have 2 problems with the above code

1. The loop will only enter a folder, change 1 file extension (and only 1 file) and leave the rest of the files UN-touched/UN-Changed.

I can assume this is due to the fact the loop goes over the each line of the txt file one time.

2.The file renaming process goes wrong for some reason.

***The output file looks like this:***

"Log1000_1.1.1.2015-02-19%3A224044.textlog"

***While is should look like this:***

Log1000_1.1.1.1_Base.1_2015-02-19%3A224044.textlog

Does any one have any idea or suggestions how to fix the code or alternativliy suggest a different one ?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.t" ') DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN ("%%~dpa.") DO (
  FOR /f "delims=" %%p IN ("%%~na.") DO (
   ECHO(REN "%%a" "%%~np.%%~nxd%%~xp"
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

The way this operates is by executing a directory-list of `*.t` files from the selected directory and applying each name to `%%a`.

`%%d` receives the drive+directory+. so the name part of `%%d` (`%%~nd`) is the name of the file's parent directory.

`%%p` similarly receives the name-part only of the file, so the name part of `%%p` is the part before the `.textlog` and the extension part is the `.textlog`.

Bang appropriate parts together with a required `.` and the rename is ready to be executed.